# I replaced httpd.conf in mountain lion and can no longer connect to localhost

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, web, localhost

I was trying to allow for my server to use the RewriteEngine in an `.htaccess` file so I went into `/private/etc/apache2` and tried to edit the `httpd.conf` file, but did not have permission.

So I duplicated it, made my edits then saved to Desktop.

I then moved to the `httpd.conf` file into the same directory as the old. It did not ask me to replace.  I then deleted the old file, and now my computer will no longer connect to localhost server.

What should I do to remedy this?

I notice that there is a `httpd.conf.bak` file in the same directory which appears to be a backup with system and wheel group privileges. I'm not sure how I restore `httpd.conf` with this while retaining system and wheel group privileges.

Thank you for any help that you can give me. I'm not familiar in this area at all.

Answer (score 1):

you can change the owner and group of any file from the console with the chown command:

```
$chown system:wheel http.conf
```

Depending what you're doing you might need to execute this with sudo, as in:

```
$sudo chown system:wheel http.conf
```

which will ask you for your password, assuming you are the administrator of your own system.